# UITableview double click the cell, call prepareSegue twice?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I **wired the cell directly to the viewController** which should be performed.

I'm not implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and **I only implement prepareForSegue**.

When I double click the cell, the prepareForSegue called twice.

How could I prevent it?

[image]

Comment: why u did not connect segue from view controller?

Comment: because click all the cell will perform the same viewController. I could do this the same if I connect segue from view controller but I think it's not the right way to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838537/prepareforsegue-vs-didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: It depends on your requirement...

Comment: my suggestion is in tableviewDidSelect  method set self.tableview.setUserIntraction to false  on segue set it true  will help

Comment: you can disable userinteraction of view in tableview didselect function

Comment: I have tried in tableviewDidSelect method set self.tableview.setUserIntraction to false and in view did appear set it to true. This will be the solution.